# Print File name to stdout

Tags: c, file, error-handling

I want to run a program, and allow user input on the same line. I check if the file exists, and if not, print

> FILE : No such file or directory

```
    FILE* filename;
    filename = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
        //validate file name
        if(!filename) {
            perror(filename);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
```

When I compile, I get the following warning:

> expected âconst char *â but argument is of type âstruct FILE *â

Comment: what is the type of `filename`? a `char *`?

Comment: I am totally confused by the wording of the question..

Comment: @EugeneSh. ha ha. Patience, my friend...let OP add some more info...

Comment: Well, I guess we should help a little. `perror` is for printing errors given by standard error numbers. Has nothing to do with file names inputted by a user.

Comment: @EugeneSh. does this help explain it? The "FILE" portion of what is printed should be the filename> I'm not sure how to print out the name of the file. I could possibly use printf(), but using %p did not work.

Comment: `fopen` is returning a file pointer, so your `filename` is actually a pointer.. `%p` format specifier tells `printf` to interpret the corresponding argument as a memory address, and print it's numerical value. `perror(filename)` doesn't make any sense at all. If you want to print your filename, use `printf("%s", argv[2]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code needs to print the *name* of the file, not the `FILE *` that has a `NULL` value.

It is not wise to print the name of a file that one has trouble opening without additional checking.  Also good to print the name in quotes, or something, to help demarcate the beginning and end of the troublesome filename.

OP's original "filename" is a weak choice for the name of the file variable as the variable is not a file's *name*.  Suggest something like "output_file".  `argv[2]` is the file's name.

```
const char *filename = argv[2];
FILE* output_file;

output_file = fopen(filename, "wb");
//validate file pointer
if(!output_file) {
   perror("Unable to open file for writing.");
   if (argc > 2 && filename) {
     fprintf(stderr, "\"%s\"\n", filename);
   }
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code above, `filename` is a `FILE *`, not a string with the name of the file.  Since `argv[2]` appears to be the filename, you could try:

```
        if(!filename) {
            perror(argv[2]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
```

...but you should first check that `argv[2]` is set (that `argc > 2`).

Answer (score 2):

```
   FILE* filename;
    filename = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
        //validate file name
        if(!filename) {
            fprintf(STDERR,"%s", filename);
            perror(" files to open: ");
        }
```

perror prints the error message followed by the string representation of the last error;

Comment: Isn't just handing over *any* string straight into `fprintf` a potential security hole?

Answer (score 0):

on this line:

```
perror(filename);
```

that is refering to a pointer to a file descriptor
not a pointer to a char string.

Suggest using:

```
perror(argv[2]);
```

BTW: perror() outputs to stderr, not stdout